# How to check whether kernel received MLD query or not?

Tags: networking, kernel, ipv6, icmp

On the Internet I found this command `netstat -p icmp6 -s` which can dump how many MLD queries received by the kernel. But I have Busybox for my system and because of this I'm unable to run `netstat` command.

Is there any alternative to this command or any file in kernel which records or store all stats related to MLDv2?

**NOTE:** I'm looking for the Multicast statistics from `netstat`.

Answer (score 0):

All that `netstat` is doing is displaying statistics that are collected by the Linux kernel under `/proc/net/*`. If you take a look at this directory using `cat /proc/net/<endpoint>` you can see all the unformatted statistics being collected.

The details of this are covered for the various endpoints is covered here: [3.3.7. /proc/net/](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-dir-net.html).

> - **arp** — Lists the kernel's ARP table. This file is particularly useful
>     for connecting a hardware address to an IP address on a system.
> - **atm/** directory — The files within this directory contain Asynchronous
>     Transfer Mode (ATM) settings and statistics. This directory is
>     primarily used with ATM networking and ADSL cards.
> - **dev** — Lists the various network devices configured on the system,
>     complete with transmit and receive statistics. This file displays the
>     number of bytes each interface has sent and received, the number of
>     packets inbound and outbound, the number of errors seen, the number of
>     packets dropped, and more.
> - **dev_mcast** — Lists Layer2 multicast groups on which each device is
>     listening.
> - **igmp** — Lists the IP multicast addresses which this system joined.
> - **ip_conntrack** — Lists tracked network connections for machines that are
>     forwarding IP connections.
> - **ip_tables_names** — Lists the types of iptables in use. This file is
>     only present if iptables is active on the system and contains one or
>     more of the following values: filter, mangle, or nat.
> - **ip_mr_cache** — Lists the multicast routing cache.
> - **ip_mr_vif** — Lists multicast virtual interfaces.
> - **netstat** — Contains a broad yet detailed collection of networking
>     statistics, including TCP timeouts, SYN cookies sent and received, and
>     much more.
> - **psched** — Lists global packet scheduler parameters.
> - **raw** — Lists raw device statistics.
> - **route** — Lists the kernel's routing table.
> - **rt_cache** — Contains the current routing cache.
> - **snmp** — List of Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) data for
>     various networking protocols in use.
> - **sockstat** — Provides socket statistics.
> - **tcp** — Contains detailed TCP socket information.
> - **tr_rif** — Lists the token ring RIF routing table.
> - **udp** — Contains detailed UDP socket information.
> - **unix** — Lists UNIX domain sockets currently in use.
> - **wireless** — Lists wireless interface data.

#### Example

If you cat `/proc/net/igmp`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/net/igmp    
Idx     Device    : Count Querier       Group    Users Timer    Reporter    
1       lo        :     0      V3    
                                010000E0     1 0:00000000               0    
2       eth0      :    26      V2    
                                260301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                9B0101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                439501E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                990101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                580101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                2A0301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                290301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                280301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                9BD901E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                2D0301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                2C0301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                370301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                050101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                620201E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                040201E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                5F0101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                520101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                2BEF01E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                4D0101E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                E00C01E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                400301E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                FB0000E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                010000E0     1 0:00000000               0    
3       eth1      :     5      V2    
                                FB0000E0     1 0:00000000               1    
                                010000E0     1 0:00000000               0
```

#### References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat
- [Linux: Multicast Routing and IGMP settings](https://sites.google.com/site/miclinuxcorner/technology/multicast-routing)